# Admin Firebase updateUser() Node SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to update login data from a firebase user using the Node admin sdk. My code looks like this:

```
var uid = req.body.uid
var objectUpdate = { "displayName": "David Coelho"};
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, objectUpdate)
  .then (function (userRecord) {
      //var id = userRecord.uid;
      //usersRef.child(id).set(userDatabase (req, res))
      res.status(200).json({ "return": "Success update user"})
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ "return": error})
  });
```

But I can not update the user. Firebase sends me the following error message:

```
"Code": "auth / internal-error",
"Message": "An internal error has occurred."
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Does this only happen for updateUser? Are you able to successfully createUser or lookup a user (getUser)? If not, are you initializing your app correctly with a credential (service account)?